Problem With a Predicate to Check if X Occurs Exactly Four Times in a List
I'm trying to write a predicate fourExactly(X, List) which checks whether the variable X appears in the List exactly four times. The predicate shoud be true if that is the case and false if not. Here is my current implementation:
fourExactly(X, List) :-
    count_occurrences(X, List, 4).
% Base case: An empty list has zero occurrences of any element.
count_occurrences(_, [], 0).
% Recursive case: If the head of the list is X, increment the count.
count_occurrences(H, [H|T], Count) :-
    count_occurrences(H, T, RestCount),
    Count is RestCount + 1.
% Recursive case: If the head of the list is not X, do not increment the count.
count_occurrences(H, [_|T], Count) :-
    count_occurrences(H, T, Count).

My current implementation works correctly if there is less than four Xs in the List(false), and if there is exactly four (true). If there is more than four, it stops functioning correctly and the output looks like this:
?- fourExactly(n, [n, n, n, n, n, a]).
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4, maybe more)
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 5, maybe more)
No (0.00s cpu)

I think this has something to do with Prolog's backchaining, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance for your help

You have a rule whose comment begins "If the head of the list on not X"; how is this enforced?

count_occurrences(H, [_|T], Count) :-
count_occurrences(H, T, Count).

That can be satisfied if H and _ are the same.

It can, but that's not what I'm looking for. count_occurrences works fine when I tested it separately. The problem is that for some reason (maybe due to how backhchaining works) when X appears more than four times, the predicate still is true which should not be the case.

It is what you are looking for, because it causes some occurrences not to be counted, making it look like there are fewer occurrences than there actually are.

Use dif, and counting from zero, and prevent counting past the maximum (if the maximum was specified):
select_eq_count(L, E, C) :- 
    % Start counting at 0
    select_eq_count_(L, E, 0, C).

% End of list, so unify the count
select_eq_count_([], _, C, C).
select_eq_count_([E|T], E, U, C) :-
    % The head of the list is equal to the element
    % Prevent exceeding the count if specified
    (   nonvar(C)
    ->  C > U
    ;   true
    ),
    U1 is U + 1,
    select_eq_count_(T, E, U1, C).
select_eq_count_([H|T], E, U, C) :-
    % Different
    dif(H, E),
    select_eq_count_(T, E, U, C).

This is perfectly general, e.g. no need to specify the count:
?- length(L, 2), select_eq_count(L, E, C).
L = [E, E],
C = 2 ;
L = [E, _A],
C = 1,
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [_A, E],
C = 1,
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [_A, _B],
C = 0,
dif(_A, E),
dif(_B, E).

... so can then count to 4, e.g.:
?- length(L, 5), select_eq_count(L, E, 4).
L = [E, E, E, E, _A],
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [E, E, E, _A, E],
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [E, E, _A, E, E],
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [E, _A, E, E, E],
dif(_A, E) ;
L = [_A, E, E, E, E],
dif(_A, E) ;
false.


fourExactly(X, Ls) :-
    include(=(X), Ls, [_,_,_,_]).

"filtering the elements of Ls to those which unify with X, the resulting list is four elements long". e.g.
?- fourExactly(n, [1,2,n,3,4,5,6,7]).
false

?- fourExactly(n, [1,2,n,3,4,n,6,7,n,n]).
true

?- fourExactly(n, [1,2,n,3,4,n,6,7,n,n,n]).
false


Thanks to @brebs and @TessellatingHeckler for your responses. Both of them worked as intended.
I took influence form @brebs solution and implemented an accumulator to basically count the number of occurrences over the pass and unify it with Count in the base case:
fourExactly(X, List) :-
    count_occurrences(X, List, 0, Count),
    Count == 4.

count_occurrences(_, [], Count, Count).
count_occurrences(X, [X|Tail], Acc, Count) :-
    NewAcc is Acc + 1,
    count_occurrences(X, Tail, NewAcc, Count).
count_occurrences(X, [Y|Tail], Acc, Count) :-
    X \= Y,
    count_occurrences(X, Tail, Acc, Count).


Instead of count_occurrences(X, List, 0, Count), Count == 4. can be the shorter: count_occurrences(X, List, 0, 4). And, dif is safer than \=. And, why remove the nonvar(C) check - it prevents going off into infinity if the list is unbounded in length. It is usual to put the list first, for first-argument indexing.
